# In Azure Container Instances, is it ok to reuse container groups or should each deployment use its own?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

When working with Azure Container Instances, is it ok to reuse an existing container group or should we be creating a new container group each time we deploy a container?

You don't have this choice when using the portal, the CLI or PowerShell, but when using the REST API, you can add a container to an existing container group. As long as the container name is unique, it will get provisioned in the existing container group and run. The question is, just because this works, is it meant to be used this way or is the designed way to create a new container group for each container deployment and once the container finished running, delete the container group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is, just because this works, is it meant to be used this
>   way or is the designed way to create a new container group for each
>   container deployment and once the container finished running, delete
>   the container group.

For your issue, I think you are right. The container group cannot be updated. To change an existing group, you need to delete and recreate it.

There are some other limitations with the container group, you can get more details about the container in Azure from this [link](https://xpirit.com/2017/11/12/containers-as-a-service-in-azure/), also about the container group.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying a new image for an existing application/task, then using an existing container group is fine. However, if this is a new set of functionality, then you should probably create a new container grouip.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my case, it's about the same application using the same image, executing multiple times. Let's say I have a list of tasks. Each task is processed by a container. Is it okay for me to keep adding new containers to the same container group for each task in the list or should I create a new container group for processing each task?